# perl referencing a hash outside of the scope that populated it (histogram)

Tags: perl, hashmap, histogram

:Hello Everybody.
I am trying to parse this data into a histogram.
When I parse up the file and substring out the values i get and nice little dataset.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
open (my $fh_tmp, '<', "/tmp/gap_output") ;
while(<$fh_tmp>) {
    my ($date, $time, $host) = split ;
    my $host_length = 12;
    my $time_length = 5;
    my $host_slice = substr $host, 0 , $host_length ;
    my $time_slice = substr $time, 0 , $time_length ;
    print "$host_slice, $time_slice\n" ;

    }
```

see - this is great.

```
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 07:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7829host, 03:10
trip7830host, 07:30
trip7830host, 07:30
trip7831host, 07:30
trip7831host, 07:30
trip7832host, 07:30
```

ultimately what I would need to get is something like this .
uniqe host, unique time and a number of times this error (which is n0t shown ) occured per minute.
Which occurs to me now - I am probably going to need a multilevel hash (ugg). HOwever until that problem -
i can't even populate a regular hash.

```
trip7829host, 03:10 10 ##########
trip7829host, 07:10 10 ##########
trip7830host, 07:30 2  ##
trip7831host, 07:30 2  ##
trip7832host, 07:30 1  #
```

I tried using a bunch of my's and our's. does not really matter though.
I kinda thought that once the gap_ids was populated, that I would not have
to declare it again - that it would live outside the scope of the while loop -
but it does not, becuase the use strict wants me to declare it again. I tried importing
those values with 'our'.

```
casper@trip0170pap:~/walt/historgram$ cat gap_histgram
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
open (my $fh_tmp, '<', "/tmp/gap_output") ;
while(<$fh_tmp>) {
    my ($date, $time, $host) = split ;
    our %gap_ids ;
    my $host_length = 12;
    my $time_length = 5;
    my $host_slice = substr $host, 0 , $host_length ;
    my $time_slice = substr $time, 0 , $time_length ;
    our ($key, $value) = ($host_slice, $time_slice) ;

    #print "$key , $value\n"  ;
    $gap_ids{$key} = $value ;
    }

while(($key, $value) =each %gap_ids) {
    printf ("%-40s %-6s", $key, $value) ;
    for (my $index =1; $index <= $value; $index++) {
    print "#" ;
    }
print "\n" ;
}



-rwxr-xr-x 1 casper casper 643 Nov 24 16:03 gap_histgram*
casper@trip0170host:~/walt/historgram$ ./gap_histgram
Variable "$key" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Variable "$value" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Variable "%gap_ids" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Variable "$key" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 19.
Variable "$value" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 19.
Variable "$value" is not imported at ./gap_histgram line 20.
Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Global symbol "%gap_ids" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 18.
Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 19.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 19.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at ./gap_histgram line 20.
Execution of ./gap_histgram aborted due to compilation errors.
```

these error are just mystifying.

Comment: Move your declaration of `%gap_ids` to before the `while` loop. You don't have to use `our` in this scenario, you can use `my`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason why you have to use global variable declaration

Your problem seems to be solvable by declaring %gap_ids outside of the first while loop. and this will hash will be accessible in the second while loop

so your code should be :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
open (my $fh_tmp, '<', "/tmp/gap_output") ;

my %gap_ids;

while(<$fh_tmp>) {
    my ($date, $time, $host) = split ;
    our %gap_ids ;
    my $host_length = 12;
    my $time_length = 5;
    my $host_slice = substr $host, 0 , $host_length ;
    my $time_slice = substr $time, 0 , $time_length ;
    my ($key, $value) = ($host_slice, $time_slice) ;

    #print "$key , $value\n"  ;
    $gap_ids{$key} = $value ;
}

while(my ($key, $value) = each %gap_ids) {
    printf ("%-40s %-6s", $key, $value) ;
    for (my $index =1; $index <= $value; $index++) {
        print "#" ;
    }
print "\n" ;
}
```

Note that I have shift %gap_ids out. and change our ($key, $value) in your first loop.

Answer (score 1):

`my` declares a variable that is local to the curly braces that it's inside.

```
use strict;

my $visible_to_the_whole_file = 7;

{
   my $only_visible_in_here = 21;
}

print "$visible_to_whole_file\n";   # works ok

print "$only_visible_in_here\n";  # WILL FAIL, there is no variable any more.
```

You can ignore `our` entirely since you're not using `package` anywhere, but it is also scoped to curly braces.  A pair of curly braces is called a "block".

Given that, you can see why you need to declare your variables, including `%gap_ids` *outside* both of the while loops, if you want the values to be seen by the code *inside* both of the while loops. (assuming `use strict`)

```
{
    my $some_variable = 21;
}
{
    print $some_variable;  # will FAIL, is no longer visible
}
```

This is what you want to do if you want the variable visible inside both blocks.

```
my $some_variable;
{
    $some_variable = 21;
}
{
    print $some_variable;  # yay, it's still 21!
}
```

What's more, if you `my` a variable inside two different blocks, you end up with two different variables.

```
{
    my $foo = 21;
}
{
    my $foo;
    print "foo is $foo\n";  # won't print 21, it's not 21 any more
}
```

Hope that's helpful!